# Business Objects - query with parameter based on a variable

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I'm writing a report in Business Objects, and need to select data dating 10 weeks from the current reporting date to the current reporting date.

I have a query element telling me the current reporting date, and I have created a variable holding the date 10 weeks ago.

```
=RelativeDate([Current Date];-10;WeekPeriod)
```

I'm now editing the data provider, and add a query filter for the date range. However, I'm not able to select the variable as an object available in the query.

I feel that I'm missing something basic. How can I select my dates based on a database object date and a predefined range of dates?

Answer (score 2):

Document variables cannot be used in the Query Panel. After your query is executed and a report has been generated, you can then filter it by using this variable.

Comment: That's a shame, since I will be retrieving way too much data. But I guess it is what it is... Thanks!

Comment: You can still create predefined filters in the universe directly so that you can use them in the Query Panel but it is more complicated since it will depends on the database (and you can't leverage Web Intelligence functions since your want to filter data at Query time). I think this article can help you to build such filters (if you are able to edit the universe): https://blogs.sap.com/2016/03/10/custom-predefined-date-range-filters-wtdmtdqtdytd-in-bo/

Comment: thanks for the link to the article. It is a good explanation, however, I don't think everyone will agree on the range of dates to include in the universe...

Comment: We have objects/variables available at the query level to filter by relative dates. There are probably 100+ options, including a folder for Rolling Time Periods that includes objects for '7 Days Ago - Yesterday', 14, 30, 60, 90, 120, and n days ago as of yesterday. Perhaps your database admin. could set these up?